# Postgres - get count of a chacter in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres/SQL, how can I get the count of a character in a column?

For example, I want to run a query which will return the number of times "X" appears in a column that has the value "XXX" - and it should return 3.

Answer (score 1):

One method is the difference of lengths:

```
select (length(col) - length(replace(col, 'X', ''))) as NumX
```